# Permanently visible Scroll Bar for ScrollView (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I just found that there is no permanent Scroll bar for ScrollView. I went through all the documentation and google but I don't think it actually exists.

How do we implement permanent Scroll Bar for `<ScrollView>`? How do we keep Scroll Bar visible?

Answer (score -12, accepted):

There is scroll bar is available on `<scrollview>`...

**here is the code...**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Image, View, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

class ScrollViewExample extends Component {
   state = {
      names: [
         {'name': 'Ben', 'id': 1},
         {'name': 'Susan', 'id': 2},
         {'name': 'Robert', 'id': 3},
         {'name': 'Mary', 'id': 4},
         {'name': 'Daniel', 'id': 5},
         {'name': 'Laura', 'id': 6},
         {'name': 'John', 'id': 7},
         {'name': 'Debra', 'id': 8},
         {'name': 'Aron', 'id': 9},
         {'name': 'Ann', 'id': 10},
         {'name': 'Steve', 'id': 11},
         {'name': 'Olivia', 'id': 12}
      ]
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <ScrollView>
               {
                  this.state.names.map((item, index) => (
                     <View key = {item.id} style = {styles.item}>
                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                     </View>
                  ))
               }
            </ScrollView>
         </View>
      )
   }
}
export default ScrollViewExample

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
   item: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      alignItems: 'center',
      padding: 30,
      margin: 2,
      borderColor: '#2a4944',
      borderWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#d2f7f1'
   }
})
```

just use import ScrollView

Comment: Yeah but can we make it visible all the time?

Comment: No, you can not show / visible ScrollIndicator all the time as far as I know. Its `ScrollView` default behaviour, Indicator will only be visible (fade-in) when you scroll list and fadeout once scroll has stopped animating.

Comment: Can you put this comment on your answer?

Comment: Yeah, this "answer" describes how to use ScrollView, but doesn't answer the original question. Thanks Pir for the clarification.

Answer (score 40):

`ScrollView` has a prop called `persistentScrollbar`.

You can set the boolean to be `true` by adding `persistentScrollbar={true}` to make scrollbars visible permanently, even when they are not in use.

**This only works for Android.**

[React Native's Official Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#persistentscrollbar)

Comment: Thanks for saying "This works only on Android" I was testing it on IOS and scratching my head why it wouldn't make the bar visible always on my iPhone.

Answer (score 17):

If you just want the user to know that the scroll is there a solution for iOS (persistentScrollbar={true} is all you need for Android)...is to set the scroll bar indicator to flash for a couple seconds after loading.

I set it to flash a half second after loading because I like the user to have moment to take in the page before the indicator flashes (flash length is preset by Apple but it fades in and out over two seconds which is more then enough for the user to know it is there)

```
export type ScrollViewRef = ScrollView & {
    flashScrollIndicators: () => void;
};

const My Page: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {

    const scrollViewRef = React.useRef<ScrollViewRef | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(function () {
            scrollViewRef.current?.flashScrollIndicators();
        }, 500);
    }, []);

    <ScrollView persistentScrollbar={true} ref={scrollViewRef}>
          my content that needs scrolling
   </ScollView>
```

Comment: This is very good UX. I will definitely use this.

Comment: I like this flashing idea better than a persistent scroll bar. Furthermore, I found that in Android, flashing scroll bar is by default. This "hack" is only needed in iOS.

Answer (score 6):

It's simple.

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true} persistentScrollbar={true}></ScrollView>
```

Comment: `persistentScrollbar` does not work on IOS.

Answer (score 0):

you can not show / visible ScrollIndicator all the time as far as I know. Its ScrollView default behaviour, Indicator will only be visible (fade-in) when you scroll list and fadeout once scroll has stopped animating

Answer (score -5):

You can set `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}` or `showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}` to set the scroll indicator visible even when not scrolling.

Usage:-

```
render(){
    return(
        <View>
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
               ...
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: At least in android the scrollbar disappears after a while.

Comment: showsHorizontalScrollIndicator and showsVerticalScrollIndicator are true by default. Setting them to false prevents the scrollbars from appearing when scrolling