# Always show scrollbar in flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a flat list in react native and I want to keep it always visible. Right now, I can see it whenever I start scrolling but I want the user to be able to see it from the moment they open the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: not sure about any prop available for flatlist, but for scrollView you can use `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}`

Comment: @AravindS But does that one show it all the time? Or only after the user starts scrolling?

Comment: I believe all time, could you please try once ?

Comment: @AravindS I did and it doesn't seem to change anything vs nothing on that field. I used vertical though

Comment: try removeClippedSubviews={false}

Comment: @ManjeetSingh doesn't work

Comment: This is not related to native-base

Comment: Similar question for ScrollView https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038519/permanently-visible-scroll-bar-for-scrollview-react-native. See the selected answer's comments.

Answer (score 4):

Do it

`persistentScrollbar={true}`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Flatlist persistentScrollbar/>
```

Comment: Why would this help the OP? Please add some clarification around the answer. Thanks!

Comment: This only applies to Android.

Answer (score -5):

Try this

```
showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}
```

Comment: This will not show the scroll bar EVERYTIME but only when user starts scrolling.